# AWS CDK: Deploying a RDS using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I want to deploy an RDS using CDK in a public subnet. But I keep on getting this error

> TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator

This is the code i am writing

```
const vpcRef= new ec2.Vpc(this, "Vpc", {
        subnetConfiguration: [
          {
            cidrMask: 24,
            name: 'Ingress',
            subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
        

          }
        ]
      });
     
     const instanceEngineInterface = rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.mysql({version:MysqlEngineVersion.VER_5_7})
    const instanc = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this,"SQLRDS",{
        publiclyAccessible:true,
        allocatedStorage:20,
        databaseName:'my-db',
        allowMajorVersionUpgrade:true,
        engine:instanceEngineInterface,
        autoMinorVersionUpgrade:true, 
        port: 3306,
        availabilityZone:'us-east-1a',
        vpc:vpcRef, 
        vpcSubnets: {subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC}})
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce this error, but if you alter the `instanceEngineInterface` variable to 
`version: rds.MysqlEngineVersion.VER_5_7` do you still get the same error?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to solve this issue by updating all my packages version to 1.100.0 ...i tried this approach before posting the question as well ...but it was left in one of the dependency as 1.98.0...i had to delete the node_modules folder ...update package.json and then run npm "install command".